# jQuery each - every X seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an array of ID's that I am returning via Laravel's eloquent.

e.g.

```
[0, 1, 4, 6, 8, 9]
```

These represent ID's in a table and then I am calling a route using those ID's.

```
/get_single_item/{id}
```

What I want is to every X seconds, move through the array and call the single_item page each time.

Currently this:

```
$.each(data, function(value) {
  console.log( value );
});
```

Dumps out all the values in one go of course, how can I only get one value, every X seconds and then start back at the beginning once at the end?

Comment: Look at `setInterval()`

Comment: With a recursive function and a timeout

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/19waccxm/

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy fiddle doing exactly what I wanted to answer :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I am after this to keep looping once it reaches the end of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***(Revised answer)***

It is fairly simple actually:

- Maintain a *current index* variable
- Use `setInterval()` to increment and clamp the variable and use the corresponding array element

```js
var array = [0, 1, 4, 6, 8, 9], current = -1;
setInterval(function() {
  current += 1;
  current %= array.length;
  console.log("callback for item #" + current + " whose value is " + array[current]);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- nothing here, look at browser console -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to print forever this is one way of doing it with a recursive function :)

```
function print_every_x_second(list, milliseconds) {
  // Get the first value and remove it from array
  var value = list.shift();
  console.log(value);
  // Put it back at the end.
  list.push(value);
  setTimeout('print_every_x_second(list, milliseconds)', milliseconds);
}
var list = [0, 1, 4, 6, 8, 9];
var milliseconds = 300;
print_every_x_second(list, milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Queue Runner

I made a small library to run a set of functions in a specific queue,

You can use it here for your specific case as the following:

## usage

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4], i = 0;

var fn = function() { 
 // your business logic is separated from the iteration logic
 if(i === arr.length) return;
 console.log( arr[i++]);
};

// execute the queue every 1 second
queue([fn], 1000, /* repeat */ true)();
```

## the library:

```
var queue = function(fn,timeout,repeat){ 
    return function(){
        var i = 0, f = fn[i], t = setInterval(function(){
            f();
            if(fn[i+1] !== undefined){
                f = fn[++i];
            }else{
                if(repeat){
                    i=0;
                    f = fn[i];
                }else{
                    clearInterval(t);
                }
            }
        }, timeout);
    }
}
```